# How to conditionally render using object properties in styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to conditonally render in **styled-components**. This code seems to work in this case.

```
background-color: ${props => (props.active ? 'Black' : 'Green')};
```

I want to rather use object properties from a JSON file and provide 2 colours to the above condition. Something similar to these below instead of **Black** and **Green**.

```
${colors['Brand/PrimaryBlack']}
${colors['Brand/PrimaryGreen']}
```

colored.json

```
{
  "colors": {
    "Brand/PrimaryBlack": "#424449",
    "Brand/PrimaryGreen": "#8ED6C9",
  }
}
```

styles.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { colors } from './colored.json'

const Tabs = styled.button`    
 background-color: ${props => (props.active ? 'Black' : 'Green')};
`
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are `'Brand/PrimaryBlack'` and `'Brand/PrimaryGreen'` keys in that `colors` object? Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? What is the `colors` object you are trying to access?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, question updated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ternary works exactly the same as your previous code, but just references the keys in your `colors` JSON, i.e. `background-color: ${props => colors[props.active ? "Brand/PrimaryBlack" : "Brand/PrimaryGreen"]};`.

```
{
  "colors": {
    "Brand/PrimaryBlack": "#424449",
    "Brand/PrimaryGreen": "#8ED6C9",
  }
}
```

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { colors } from './colored.json'

const Tabs = styled.button`    
  background-color: ${props => colors[props.active ? "Brand/PrimaryBlack" : "Brand/PrimaryGreen"]};
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you desire using styled components in the following way:

```
 background-color: ${(props) =>
    props.active ? colors["Brand/PrimaryGreen"] : colors["Brand/PrimaryBlack"]};
```

[Find the working CodeSandBox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-sky-0wfj6?file=/src/App.js:165-277)

Answer (score 1):

Inside of [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) you pass any valid JavaScript code inside of `${}` expression even call to function so if you have an object which you want to access some keys you can just access those keys as you would do in a normal JavaScript code. so if you have an object `colors` with some properties you can  access it inside of you Styled Component like this

```
const colors = {
    "Brand/PrimaryGreen": "green",
    "Brand/PrimaryBlack": "black"
};

const Comp = styled.div`
    background: ${props => props.active? colors["Brand/PrimaryBlack"] : colors["Brand/PrimaryGreen"]};
    color: #fff;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
<TagName active={this.state.active}>Test</TagName>
```

And in your styles something like this:

```
const TagName = styled.button`
  width: 100%;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 0.2;

  ${({ active }) => active && `
    background: blue;
  `}
`;
```